# Convert resolution of geojson file from 1:10 to 1:110

Tags: geojson

After searching a while I finally found a [geojson file](https://gist.github.com/cmunns/76fb72646a68202e6bde) of the continents. But it is large file (even gzipped) and I do not need the high resolution (1:10). Can I somehow convert it smaller resolution (1:110)?

Comment: I think you mean to ask from 1.110 to 1.10?

Comment: there is nice module [geojson-precision](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-precision) to reduce the precision.